# Creating new extension in Asterisk using Java

Tags: java, asterisk

From my java program I want to add a new Extension to my Asterisk server. Anyone please guide me on how to. I am totally new on Asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

From your java app write to db in correct format and use sip realtime engine

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip